# What's random in Caret if the hold out is fixed for cross validation

Tags: r, cross-validation, caret

I tried to fix the folds for cross validation in Caret. But there is still some randomness returned by the train function. See code below. Don't they should return the same?

```
library(caret)
set.seed(123) 
x=matrix(rnorm(1000),500,2)
colnames(x)=c("x1","x2")
y=x[,1]+x[,2]+rnorm(500,0,0.1)
foldlist=createFolds(y,k=4)
train.control <- trainControl(method="cv", number=4, indexOut = foldlist, returnData = TRUE, returnResamp="all")
test=train(x=x, y=y, method = "glm", trControl = train.control)
print(test$resample)
test=train(x=x, y=y, method = "glm", trControl = train.control)
print(test$resample)
```

Comment: does `trainControl` take its own `seeds` argument?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not super clear in the vignette, but if you check (`?trainControl`):

```
indexOut: a list (the same length as ‘index’) that dictates which data
          are held-out for each resample (as integers). If ‘NULL’, then
          the unique set of samples not contained in ‘index’ is used.
```

You just need to provide the index, it will figure out the fold to leave out. If you don't provide `index`, and number of folds and `indexOut`, it will ignore `indexOut`. So do it like this:

```
foldlist = createFolds(y, k = 4, list = TRUE, returnTrain = TRUE)
train.control <- trainControl(method="cv",index = foldlist, returnData = TRUE, returnResamp="all")

test=train(x=x, y=y, method = "glm", trControl = train.control)
> print(test$resample)
        RMSE  Rsquared        MAE parameter Resample
1 0.10360315 0.9945046 0.08549719      none    Fold1
2 0.10423416 0.9947764 0.08200349      none    Fold2
3 0.09873174 0.9941630 0.07853604      none    Fold3
4 0.08950837 0.9958181 0.07217276      none    Fold4

test=train(x=x, y=y, method = "glm", trControl = train.control)
> print(test$resample)
        RMSE  Rsquared        MAE parameter Resample
1 0.10360315 0.9945046 0.08549719      none    Fold1
2 0.10423416 0.9947764 0.08200349      none    Fold2
3 0.09873174 0.9941630 0.07853604      none    Fold3
4 0.08950837 0.9958181 0.07217276      none    Fold4
```

Comment: important question: does `createFolds` generate output which is reproducible by `set.seed`?

Comment: if you set the seed before running createFolds, it will always give you the same output